# Visual C++ CUSTOMBUILD : error : Additional include file afxhh.h

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to compile visual C++ application in Visual studio 2010 express edition, it's getting failed  saying the error as "CUSTOMBUILD : error : Additional include file afxhh.h". Expecting some help to fix it....

Answer (score 0):

The Express editions of Visual Studio do not include the MFC libraries. You will not be able to compile applications that rely on MFC headers, like `afxhh.h`.

AFX (Application Framework Extensions) was the original name for MFC during development, and that name sticks around as the prefix to many functions and header files.

In order to develop MFC applications, you need to purchase a full version of Visual Studio.